# Bar Chart with two values in "Change On", skip bars with value 0

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Reports bar chart based on the following sql statement:

```
Select 'Max' as Name, '2018-05-02' as Day
union all select 'Max', '2018-05-02'
union all select 'Max', '2018-05-02'
union all select 'Fritz', '2018-05-02'
union all select 'Fritz', '2018-05-02'
union all select 'Fritz', '2018-05-03'
union all select 'Fritz', '2018-05-03'
union all select 'Fritz', '2018-05-03'
union all select 'Max', '2018-05-04'
```

That is I have data for three days and on each day, some names may appear multiple times. I now want to show a chart where for each day, I see how often each name appears. I try with the following setting:

[image]

What I get as a result is quite close to what I want to achieve:

[image]

However, the problem is that the chart reserves space for all two names for each day. This becomes a problem when there are more than two names and only a few names appear each day.

Like in this example with a lot more names that each only appear on a few days:

```
Select 'Max' as Name, '2018-05-02' as Day
union all select 'Max', '2018-05-02'
union all select 'Max', '2018-05-02'
union all select 'Hans', '2018-05-02'
union all select 'Beate', '2018-05-02'
union all select 'Luise', '2018-05-02'
union all select 'Sandra', '2018-05-02'
union all select 'Fritz', '2018-05-02'
union all select 'Fritz', '2018-05-02'
union all select 'Fritz', '2018-05-03'
union all select 'Fritz', '2018-05-03'
union all select 'Fritz', '2018-05-03'
union all select 'Max', '2018-05-04'
union all select 'Rainer', '2018-05-04'
union all select 'Elvira', '2018-05-04'
union all select 'Silvia', '2018-05-04'
```

[image]

For each day, space is reserved for every name that appears on any of the days. Is it possible to make Crystal Reports skip these columns and only reserve space for columns that have a value other than 0?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to accomplish that in the built in column chart of Crystal Reports. At least, not "naturally".

But, depending on your requisites, you may try something as described below. But you will have to play with data and options to try to get something presentable.

The basic idea is to format data so that the chart will be a common column chart (without groups). This way, you get rid of the "zero columns".

First, change your select command to something like this:

```
select Name, Day, Day + ': ' + Name as DayAndName, Count(*) as Count from (
    Select 'Max' as Name, '2018-05-02' as Day
    union all select 'Max', '2018-05-02'
    union all select 'Max', '2018-05-02'
    union all select 'Hans', '2018-05-02'
    union all select 'Beate', '2018-05-02'
    union all select 'Luise', '2018-05-02'
    union all select 'Sandra', '2018-05-02'
    union all select 'Fritz', '2018-05-02'
    union all select 'Fritz', '2018-05-02'
    union all select 'Fritz', '2018-05-03'
    union all select 'Fritz', '2018-05-03'
    union all select 'Fritz', '2018-05-03'
    union all select 'Max', '2018-05-04'
    union all select 'Rainer', '2018-05-04'
    union all select 'Elvira', '2018-05-04'
    union all select 'Silvia', '2018-05-04'
) X
group by Name, Day
```

Then you configure your column chart like this:
[image]

The first result will be ugly. Then the challenge is how to make it presentable. Maybe it is not possible to make it good enough. But there will be no "zero columns".

A tip to begin would be to use column labels instead of the legend and to pay attention about the order.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it misses some important requirements (for the use-case that the question originated from): group the columns by days and use the same colour for the same person.

Comment: Yoy may try another probably-not-good-possibility: group details by date and plot each date in a separate graph. But I think the result would be even worse and probably the colors would not match. I did not try this one, I'm just thinking outloud.